# MySQL user belongs to organization

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a user table setup where a user can either belong to a `Supplier` or a `Customer` organization, which can have multiple users.

My original idea for the `User` table was to have a `customerID` and a `SupplierID` in the user table, out of which one will be filled, based on the organization the user belongs to. This does however not feel right, but I feel like maintaining two linking tables for this is overkill as well.

What would be the best practice in this case? I do not expect there to be any more organizations added in the future, but I do want to futureproof the application, by allowing multiple users to belong to the same organization.

Answer (score 0):

you can design user or organization table with a column organization type which has value: supplier/customer and a column for organizationId